# Flutter file upload with Dio empty in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, flutter

I'm unable to upload files using the `Dio` plugin and I can not figure out where's the problem. In Laravel the request is always empty.

What have I done so far:

1. Double check if the file path really exists using `existsSync()` function
2. Changed the `Content-Type` to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`
3. Validated if the file is actually being uploaded - seems yes (?)

This is my flutter code:

```
File myFile = new File('/storage/emulated/0/Download/demo.docx');

FormData form = new FormData.from({
  'title': 'Just testing',
  'file': new UploadFileInfo(myFile, 'demo.docx')
});
```

Before sending through `POST` i checked if the file exists and returns true

```
print(myFile.existsSync());
```

And set the `Content-type` properly

```
Response response = await Dio().post(
  myUrl,
  data: form,
  options: new Options(
    contentType: ContentType.parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"),
  ),
);
```

Printing the result of the `form` returns

```
I/flutter (27929): ----dio-boundary-0118165894
I/flutter (27929): Content-Disposition: form-data; name="title"

I/flutter (27929): ----dio-boundary-1759467036
I/flutter (27929): Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="demo.docx"
I/flutter (27929): Content-Type: application/octet-stream
```

Which I believe indicates that the file is being uploaded.

Now in laravel whenever i output the content received it always comes null the key `file`, but the key `title` comes with data.

The code `print_r(json_encode($request->all()))` retrieves

```
{"title":"Just testing","file":{}}
```

The same goes for `print_r(json_encode($request->file('file')))`.

What am i missing?

Comment: Maybe parse the file content to a base64 string and then send that base64 string to your API.

Comment: @DeesOomens can't do it because of the size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solved.**

This took me a while to figure it out, but i end up realizing there's two problems with this approach:

1. Laravel `$request` is empty, but `$_FILES` is not
2. Sending multiple files can not be sent using arrays as the [documentation](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/dio) tells

So, in order to achieve my goal which allows the user to select multiple files dynamically and upload them at the same time, here's the logic behind:

## Flutter

The form must be created without setting the files right away:

```
FormData form = new FormData.from(
{
    'title': 'Just testing',
});
```

Since the function `.from` is a `Map<String, dynamic>` values can be added after.

```
/* 
 * files = List<String> containing all the file paths
 *
 * It will end up like this:
 *  file_1  => $_FILES
 *  file_2  => $_FILES 
 *  file_3  => $_FILES
 */
for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    form.add('file_' + i.toString(),
        new UploadFileInfo(new File(files[i]), files[i].toString()));
}
```

There is no need to set up a different `Content-Type`, therefore this is enough:

```
Response response = await Dio().post(myUrl, data: form);
```

## Laravel / PHP

Forget about accessing the `file` through `$request->file()` and instead use the old school approach.

```
$totalFiles = count($_FILES);

for ($i = 0; $i < $totalFiles; $i++)
{
    $file = $_FILES['file_' . $i];

    // handle the file normally ...
    $fileName       = basename($file['name']);
    $fileInfo       = pathinfo($file);
    $fileExtension = $fileInfo['extension'];

    move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $path);
}
```

Comment: Hi, I am having the same scenario. I want to upload multi image + files from form. Can you tell me how you have saved the values in "files" array? I am having an error of type 'UploadFileInfo' is not a subtype of type 'String'.

Please let me know because I have not found any help regarding this. Thanks

Comment: @FaranKhan `files` is an array of strings `List<String> filePaths = [];` that contains the list of file paths.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but this may help someone.
this solution works for me, upload multi-file to server use Flutter Dio library and Laravel as backend. correct me if I did it wrong.

## Flutter

```
BaseOptions _dioOption({@required String token}) {
    BaseOptions options = new BaseOptions(baseUrl: baseUrl, headers: {
      Headers.acceptHeader: Headers.jsonContentType,
      Headers.contentTypeHeader: Headers.jsonContentType,
      "Authorization": "Bearer $token"
    });
    return options;   
}

  dioPostProduct( {@required ProductToUpload productToUpload,
                  @required String url, String token}) async {

    //productToUpload.images is a List<File>
    List<Object> filesData = new List<Object>();

    for (final file in productToUpload.images) {
      filesData.add(MultipartFile.fromFileSync(file.path,
          filename: file.path.split('/').last));
    }

    FormData data = FormData.fromMap({
      "subcategory_id": productToUpload.subcategory_id,
      "name": productToUpload.name,
      "detail": productToUpload.detail,
      "price": productToUpload.price,
      "condition_id": productToUpload.condition_id,
      "images": filesData,
    });

    Dio dio = new Dio(_dioOption(token: token));

    Response response;
    response = await dio.post(url, data: data);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print(response.data);
    }

  }
```

## Laravel

For php resize image I use library [intervention](http://image.intervention.io/)

```
$images = Collection::wrap(request()->file('images'));
$directory = '/product_images'; //make sure directory is exist
foreach ($images as $image) {
   $basename = Str::random();
   $original = $basename . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
   $thumbnail = $basename . '_thumb.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
  Image::make($image)
  ->fit(400, 400)
  ->save(public_path($directory . '/' . $thumbnail));
  $image->move(public_path($directory), $original);
}
```