# Upload multiple files from flutter to Laravel backend

Tags: laravel, flutter

I'm trying to upload multiple files from flutter to laravel backend, I use the file_picker package to select the files from the phone, then I use Dio package to send them as formData to the backend, here's my function

```
Future<String> _uploadFiles(List<PlatformFile> paths) async {
    print(paths);
    FormData formData = FormData.fromMap({
      "user_id": "a287f309-ff1a-4352-9576-770bb72192bb",
      "service_type": "ترجمة",
      "translator_level": "معتمد",
      "translating_speed": "السرعة العادية",
      "summary": "ملخص الطلب",
      "lang_from": "العربية",
      "lang_to": "الانجليزية",
      "specialization": "تقني",
      "files": paths
    });

    try {
      Response response = await Dio()
          .post('http://192.168.43.139:8000/api/orders/create', data: formData);
      print(response.data);
    } on DioError catch (e) {
      print(e.response.data);
    }
  }
```

But I'm getting an error regarding the files uploading, the laravel backend can't parse the files which are send by this way, anyone know who to solve this problem ?

Comment: can you post what error you are getting?

Comment: It's 500 Internal server error, which in my backend is thrown when the files are missing or if they are not even files (for example if I put a string as a value for the files property)

Comment: check this answer: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/55479848/10239185]